# Appending/Prepending "" and = in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to prepend =" then append " to a range to cells in excel. The = sign and " " need to be visible in the cell.

I currently have:

[image: Start]

And I am trying to make the cell look like this:

[image: Goal]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future, you can use the `'` character to tell Excel you want to use a symbol, so in your above example, if you simply type `'="BRIS"`, you'll get the solution you want, without typing all of those " marks.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I answered my own question...

The formula would be `= "="&""""&D2&""""`